# Transpose columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to take the following data;

```
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        ID       |       Make      |       Model     |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        A1       |       Ford      |       Fiesta    |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        A2       |       Peugeot   |       106       |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

And transpose it so that it looks like so;

```
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        ID       |     FieldName   |    FieldValue   |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        A1       |       Make      |       Ford      |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        A1       |       Model     |       Fiesta    |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        A2       |       Make      |       Peugeot   |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|        A2       |       Model     |       106       |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

Is this possible within SQL?

Comment: Do a UNION ALL, one SELECT for Make, and one for Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest doing this using `cross apply`:

```
select t.id, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('make', t.make),
             ('model', t.model)
     ) v(fieldname, fieldvalue);
```

SQL Server also offers `unpivot` and `union all` which can be used for this purpose.  However, lateral joins (the technical name for what `apply` does) are quite powerful and efficient.

Comment: oh, never heard of that trick with `values` in apply :) Nice!

Answer (score 1):

you can use unpivot as below:

```
Select * from #temp 
unpivot (fieldvalue for fieldName in([make],[model])) p
```